# How to write a generic function in c#?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to write a generic function in c# which tries to parse a string based on the type.

Here is what I tried

```
    public static T convertString<T>(string raw)
    {
        if( typeof(T) == DateTime ){
            DateTime final;
            DateTime.TryParseExact(raw, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out final);
            return final;
         }

        if( typeof(T) == int ){
            int final;
            Int32.TryParse(raw, out final);
            return final;
        }

    }
```

How can I correct this function to work?

Comment: Generics that have very different implementations based on the type of `T` don't usually make sense. One could call `convertString<SomeRandomType>` and your method would not know how to handle it.

Comment: @EricJ. can you please give me an example?

Comment: @MikeA An example of what?

Comment: @Servy example of how to use `convertString<SomeRandomType>` syntax

Comment: @MikeA That has nothing whatsoever to do with Eric's comment.  It doesn't even make sense.

Comment: `Generics should be actually generic, and work the same on any possible type` http://ericlippert.com/2015/10/14/casts-and-type-parameters-do-not-mix/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try something like that :

```
public static T ConvertFromString<T>(string raw)
{
    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(raw);
}

// Usage
var date = ConvertFromString<DateTime>("2015/01/01");
var number = ConvertFromString<int>("2015");
```

**Edit: Support for TryConvert**

Otherwise you can create a function that will try to convert the input string:

```
public static bool TryConvertFromString<T>(string raw, out T result)
{
    result = default(T);
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof (T));
    if (!converter.IsValid(raw)) return false;

    result = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(raw);
    return true;
}

// Usage
DateTime result;
if (!TryConvertFromString<DateTime>("this is not a date", out result))
{

}
```

Comment: can you please explain how this works? how will this try to parse datetime or int ?

Comment: @MikeA, I've updated my post. Do you need explanations on how generic type works in general ?

Comment: Thank you. if I do execute this `convertString<int>("Mike A")` will this gives me an error or will it return an incorrect value?

Comment: @MikeA, I've added a new version of the function to support TryConvert. Please mark the answer as valid if it's ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this more generic and not rely on a string parameter provided the type U implements IConvertible - this means you have to specify two type parameters though:

```
 public static T ConvertValue<T,U>(U value) where U : IConvertible
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to check if you can convert U to T before ?